# AWS time based scaling of encrypted volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, autoscaling

I have setup time based scaling on an ELB group to scale completely down to 0 instances on off hours and to start a new instance at the beginning of the next day. It has been working great, however it isn't encrypting the new instance.

I have been searching for a way to encrypt the volume on the new instance that gets created each day and haven't had much luck. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the created volume EBS?

Comment: Yes, it is EBS created

Comment: Check this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/protect-your-data-with-new-ebs-encryption/ when you are creating a AMI you have to encrypt the volume

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the AMI you are currently using in your auto-scaling group is unencrypted. So any EBS volumes created from that AMI will also be unencrypted. You need to [create an encrypted AMI by copying your current one and specifying an encryption key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIEncryption.html). Then you need to change your auto-scaling group to use the new encrypted AMI. All EBS volumes created from the encrypted AMI will also be encrypted.